# The assembly is created after its built or deployment?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly-references, build

I was wondering when do the runtime create the assembly of my sharepoint project, is it after building it or after it deployment ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Build in Visual Studio will generate/create the assembly.  Deploying it will simply register it with the SharePoint platform.

Update:
As David added, the "Deploy" command in Visual Studio does also trigger the build event before it is deployed to SharePoint.  The act of deployment within SharePoint though, simply registers it with SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Running Deploy in VS will build it, compile the package WSP file, then deploy it to SharePoint.